# Creating another drop down based on option chosen in a drop down menu

Tags: javascript

I have a drop down being created, it starts with one that has three options "Choose Gender" "Male?", "Female".  What I want to know is how to make it so that when male is selected, a new drop down menu is created with the options of "Choose your race!", "Human", "Dwarf", "Orc".  What I am doing now does not seem to work.  I have to use JavaScript (not JQuery)

What I have so far:

```
var step1 = ["Choose Gender?", "Male", "Female"];
var step2 = [["Choose your race!", "Human", "Dwarf", "Orc"],["Choose your race!", "Elf", "Dwarf"]];
var step3 = [["Human Class", "Warrior", "Sorcerer", "Theif"], ["Elf Class", "Cleric", "Necromancer", "Priest"], ["Dwarf Class", "Cannonner", "Rifelman", "Engineer"], ["Orc Class", "Beserker","Warlock", "Shaman"]];

function init() {
    menuCreate(step1);
    if (selectValue == step1[1]){

        menuCreate(step2);

    }
}
function menuCreate(step2){
    //console.log(step1);
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("mainDiv");
    var titleElement = document.createElement("h1");

    titleElement.setAttribute('style','color:white');
    titleElement.setAttribute('id','guide');

    var selectForm = document.createElement('select');

    selectForm.id = "form";
    myDiv.appendChild(selectForm);



    for (var i=0; i< step2.length; i++){
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = step2[i];
        option.text = step2[i];
        selectForm.appendChild(option);

    }



} // end menuCreate()

function getSelectValue(){
    var selectValue = document.getElementById("form").value;

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! even if it is just a hint to get started! I am new to JavaScript.  All selects have to be dynamically created in JavaScript.  I'm also not allowed to use innerhtml/innertext, the drop downs need to be dynamically created using JS

Comment: selectValue  is ?

Comment: Open the console. It will tell you at least 2 errors ive found...

Comment: @lgbaryya I'm trying to get selectValue to be whatever the option selected in the drop down menu is.

Comment: @Jonas w, the console does not tell me what errors there are right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the body element by tag name, and add to the innerHTML of it to create more HTML elements, as shown in my JSFiddle code:
https://jsfiddle.net/qx9cwnuk/

```
function create() {
    var name = document.getElementById('s1').value;
  document.getElementById('d1').innerHTML = "You selected " + name + "<br/><select><option>Option 1</option><option>Option 2</option><option>Option 3</option></select>";
}
<select id="s1">
  <option value="male">Male</option>
  <option value="female">Female</option>
  <option value="orc">Orc</option>
</select>
<button onclick="create()">Select</button><br/>
<div id="d1"></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the guidelines for this say I cant use innerHTML/innerText.  Sorry should have mentioned that above, edited my question. all drop downs have to be dynamically created.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in a slightly neater way if you use make use of events. When you create the options for the "step1" dropdown, attach an event to each of the objects. There are several ways to do that, my recommendation would be:

```
option.addEventListener("click", <someFunction>);
```

Where someFunction generates your next level of dropdown.
Now you probably want to pass along some information to that next function so you could use an anonymous function like this:

```
option.addEventListener("click", () => {
    someFunction(option.value, otherUsefulInformation);
});
```

Excuse the fancy notation, think of it as a way to execute a statement inside of "addEventListener" instead of giving it a function directly. Now you could nest this as deeply as you like and pass along all relevant information. The last level of this nesting could execute some action based on the information passed along to it.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Code example:

```
generateLevel1(optionsArray){
    for(<each element in optionsArray){
        let option = <new dom element>
        <do customization and stuff to option>
        option.addEventListener("click", () => {
            // the following statements will be executed when this option is clicked
            if(option == male)
                generateLevel2(nextOptionsArray);
            if(option == female)
                generateLevel2(otherNextOptionsArray);
        }
    }
}
```

Using a bunch of if statements is maybe not the best way to do this but if you have a small number of options it will get the job done. Also you might have noticed me using "let" instead of "var". This may or may not be important in this type of nesting, I haven't written js in a long time so I don't know. I know I'm not being super descriptive but you only asked for a hint.

Comment: is there a way to do this for certain options in the drop down?  For example I only want a certain one created if the user clicks on  "Male" in the first drop-down.

Comment: At any given level of the dropdown, you are calling a function to generate the next level. You can pass along any variables you like into that generator function, including what options it should have. So if the user clicked "Male" you could maybe pass in an array of options for the next level.